# Sphinx values for attributes reported as None

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When I use Sphinx autodoc to document a class, the values for the attributes are always reported, (as it says it should [here](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/changes.html), under #437) but always as "= None"

```
Attribute = None
    Some Documentation
```

I include it like

```
.. autoclass:: core.SomeClass
   :members:
```

And my code looks like

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = "value" #: Some Documentation
```

Is there a way to either make the "= None" report the real value, or make it disappear?

Comment: where are you seeing ``= None``?

Comment: Here, for example: http://readthedocs.org/docs/domination-game/en/latest/games.html#domination.core.GameStats. It occurs everywhere where I'm using `self.attribute = ...` in combination with `autoclass:: .. :members:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure this has to do with the fact that your attribute is an instance attribute. It does not get a value until the class is instantiated. Sphinx imports modules in order to inspect them, but it does not instantiate any classes.

So the "real value" is not known by Sphinx, and `None` is output. I don't think you can make it go away easily (but I suppose anything is possible if you are prepared to patch the Sphinx source code...). If you don't like this, you could document attributes in the docstring of the class instead.

Class attributes that are documented using the same markup scheme ([described here](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=data#directive-autoattribute)) do get their values displayed in the rendered output. But there is no clear indication that makes it easy for the reader to distinguish between class and instance attributes. Maybe Sphinx could be a little more helpful here.

Comment: I don't think the working hypothesis of this answer is correct. I'm experiencing the problem (i.e. - "<attribute> = None" showing up in the generated documentation) for class attributes defined and initialized outside of the __init__() function. These are documented, using the "#: ..." comment variant placed after the attribute on the same line.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a GitHub project or similar where we can look at this?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/capn-freako/PyBERT/blob/8c63d28220edc000e9503082e05c6257cd9cee7c/pybert/pybert.py#L315

Comment: Check out the attributes of the PyBERT class like bit_rate, for instance. Note that the comments in this version are not, yet, correct. (They're missing the colon after the pound sign.) I'm working with corrected comments, in my own sandbox, which haven't been pushed, yet.

Comment: Is the rendered PyBERT documentation available online somewhere? Can you provide a [mcve] that does not require me to clone your entire project and install a lot of dependencies?

Comment: HEAD exhibits the problem, while HEAD^ does not. The differences between the two are: HasTraits vs. object as the superclass, and Int vs int as the type of cAtt.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (cAtt = None in the documentation). I suggest that you post a new question.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for your time! Happy holidays. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932680/sphinx-autodoc-incorrectly-assigning-value-none-to-class-attributes-when-trai

Answer (score 10):

There will be an `:annotation:` option (see [pull-request](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/pull-request/109)) in the upcoming version 1.2 of sphinx (and in the second beta).

For `autodata`/`autoattribute` you can then force a specific value or suppress it.
So in order to print no value for the attribute you would put:

```
.. autoclass:: core.SomeClass

   .. autoattribute:: attribute
      :annotation:
```

Currently it only works with `autodata`/`autoattribute` directly and not recursively with `automodule`/`autoclass`.

Comment: This appears to only work with class attributes. Tested using Sphinx 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

For the current version of Sphinx, you can put a monkeypatch in the `conf.py` of your project that fixes this problem:

```
from sphinx.ext.autodoc import (
    ClassLevelDocumenter, InstanceAttributeDocumenter)

def iad_add_directive_header(self, sig):
    ClassLevelDocumenter.add_directive_header(self, sig)

InstanceAttributeDocumenter.add_directive_header = iad_add_directive_header
```

This is discussed in [Sphinx issue #2044](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2044)

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be an issue. I worked around it with:

```
class ValueDoc:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text
```

And then define the attribute at the class level like:

```
#: documentation for foo
foo = ValueDoc('text to show up after =')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get annotations working for instance attributes. I chose to just hide the attribute values in my theme.

**Example html**

```
<dl class="attribute">
  <dt>
    <code class="descName">Attribute</code>
    <em class="property"> = None</em>
  </dt>
</dl>
```

**Theme CSS to hide `= None`**

```
dd dl.attribute em.property { display: none }
```

Comment: There is an undocumented directive called `autoinstanceattribute` that you can try. It is unclear if this directive just needs to be documented or if `autoattribute` really is supposed to also handle instance attributes. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/904#issuecomment-68577602.

Comment: So the `.. autoinstanceattribute` directive with a blank `:annotation:` option does successfully take away the value! It seems this implementation is kind of a mess through 1.5.