# autodoc failing on django ImageField

Tags: django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm attempting to use sphinx to document the *django* app I'm writing. So far I have my `code.rst` setup to look at `models.py`, and when I run `make html` I get the automatic documentation, however I get a warning:

> WARNING: autodoc can't import/find attribute 'myapp.models.MyModel.image', it reported error: "image", please check your spelling and sys.path

The entire tracelog is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blah\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 326, in import_object
    obj = self.get_attr(obj, part)
  File "C:\blah\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 232, in get_attr
    return safe_getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
  File "C:\blah\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 70, in safe_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: image
```

`MyModel.image` is an image field, simply on the model defined as:

```
#: image file location for ``MyModel``
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
```

If I change image to `models.Charfield` for example it runs fine. Is there any reason why an `ImageField` would cause sphinx issues?

my code.rst:

```
.. automodule:: dynamicbanners.models
   :members:
```

Comment: After further reading could this be anything to do with the fact that sphinx doesn't initialise the model class? Obviously all my attributes show up as ``my_attr = None`` in the docs because they weren't initialised, and I've [read answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14503035/2547709) that suggest this might be a bug? I'd be quite surprised that NO-ONE else has come across this issue yet. It seems oddly specific towards ``models.ImageField`` (Although having just tested, it also does this with ``models.FileField``.

Comment: added my code.rst just in case. Although right now I'd accept the answer if someone told me they had successfully managed to use autodoc on an ImageField before :)

Comment: @mzjn: That bug report link is broken now.  (It prompts you to log in or create an account, then says Access Denied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading the comments it seems this is a quirk of Django that messes with `sphinx.ext.autodoc`. Hopefully a fix will be dropped into Django 1.6 soon, or failing that I  think the upcoming 1.2 version of Sphinx might provide a way around it, but for now I'll need to find some sort of workaround.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm seeing exactly the same issue with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield on Django 1.6.5 and sphinx 1.2.2.

Comment: If anyone else is interested, the work-around for jsonfield is slightly different: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1254/autodoc-fails-to-handle-descriptors-with#comment-11070601

Comment: @CharlBotha: That bug report link is broken now.  (It prompts you to log in or create an account, then says Access Denied).

Comment: @user9876, new link to bug report: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1254

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in Django 1.8 - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12568