# How can I generate useful documentation of Python object constants with Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have some 'constants' in a Python module (`vengeance.directions`) for which I am trying to generate sensible documentation using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). The values of these 'constants' are objects (of type: `Direction`) rather than literal values and don't generate particularly useful documentation:

```
#: North (opposite: SOUTH).
NORTH = _NORTH_SOUTH.direction

#: South (opposite: NORTH).
SOUTH = _NORTH_SOUTH.opposite

#: East (opposite: WEST).
EAST = _EAST_WEST.direction

#: West (opposite: EAST).
WEST = _EAST_WEST.opposite
```

The `.rst` file contains this:

```
.. automodule:: vengeance.directions
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

And the generated output looks (more or less) like this:

> vengeance.directions.EAST = `<vengeance.game.Direction object at 0x1046fd690>`
>
> > East (opposite: WEST).
>
> vengeance.directions.NORTH = `<vengeance.game.Direction object at 0x1046fd750>`
>
> > North (opposite: SOUTH).
>
> vengeance.directions.SOUTH = `<vengeance.game.Direction object at 0x1046fd790>`
>
> > South (opposite: NORTH).
>
> vengeance.directions.WEST = `<vengeance.game.Direction object at 0x1046fd6d0>`
>
> > West (opposite: EAST).

Literal values produce much more helpful documentation, for example:

> vengeance.directions.EAST = 2

I'd like to be able to produce something similar, removing the `<vengeance.game.Direction object at ...>` and perhaps replacing it with the value of the `Direction.__str__()` method. This would also prevent having to add additional documentation. In other words I'd like to be able to simply write:

```
NORTH = _NORTH_SOUTH.direction
SOUTH = _NORTH_SOUTH.opposite
EAST = _EAST_WEST.direction
WEST = _EAST_WEST.opposite
```

to generate:

> vengeance.directions.EAST = East (opposite: WEST)
>
> vengeance.directions.NORTH = North (opposite: SOUTH)
>
> vengeance.directions.SOUTH = South (opposite: NORTH)
>
> vengeance.directions.WEST = West (opposite: EAST)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In [Sphinx 1.2](http://sphinx-doc.org/changes.html#release-1-2-released-dec-10-2013) (released Dec 10, 2013), there is a new [`annotation`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute) option for `autoattribute` and `autodata` (but not `automodule` and `autoclass`) that might help:

> Autodoc directives for module data and attributes now support an `annotation` option, so that the default display of the data/attribute value can be overridden.

This does not make things as simple as envisioned in the question, but it is an improvement.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14503035/407651).