# How can I document a constant (module level variable) with sphinx (docstring without data)?

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to document a constant by its docstring. I don't want to let the value to show up. If I have a long list, Sphinx will include it completely which I don't want. It would be okay for me if only an excerpt would be shown (with ellipsis or whatever). But not thousands of list elements.

```
module_level_variable2 = 98765
"""int: Module level variable documented inline.

The docstring may span multiple lines. The type may optionally be specified
on the first line, separated by a colon.
"""
```

I've tried the following:

```
.. autoclass:: module_level_variable2
```

does not show the docstring at all.

```
.. autodata:: module_level_variable2
```

does show docstring and the data.

```
.. automethod:: module_level_variable2
```

and
    .. autoattribute:: module_level_variable2

do not show anything in the documentation (not even the name of the variable).

```
.. autofunction:: module_level_variable2
```

does show the docstring only. This is almost what I want. However, it considers a constant as a function() by adding parentheses to it - which is wrong (why a warning is raised on `make html`!

I went through http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/ext/autodoc.html but could not find a switch to tell `.. autodata::` not to show the data itself (but the docstring only).

**SOLUTION**

```
.. autodata:: module_level_variable2
   :annotation:
```

Comment: The `autodata` directive takes an `:annotation:` option (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autodata).

Comment: Similar to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20057854/407651, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26026819/407651

Comment: @mzjn thanks, `:annotation:` is what I needed.