# Sphinx autodoc incorrectly assigning value 'None' to class attributes, when Traits are used

Tags: python, python-sphinx, traitsui, autodoc

I'm seeing Python *class* attributes incorrectly assigned the value, `None`, in *Sphinx* `autodoc` generated documentation, when *Traits* are used.

I have a simple test case with instructions for observing the error, here:
https://github.com/capn-freako/SphinxTest

It shows that:

1. When `object` is used as the superclass, and `int` is the class attribute's type, the generated documentation is as expected.
2. When `HasTraits` is used as the superclass and `Int` is the class attribute's type, the generated documentation is incorrect.